# Creating trigger for multiple table insert operation

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have created table in Slq yog which was working fine. then i created same on mysql terminal.
this also executes with no error:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER INSERT ON table2  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO record VALUES (id,NEW.sent); 
INSERT INTO temp values (id,NEW.sent,NEW.pcount,NEW.ncount); 

END

$$ DELIMITER ;
```

But after this when I enter `show triggers` or any other command it ask for `->` no input

so I need to terminate mysql. Then when I check `show triggers` says `Empty set`.

Where is the mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER INSERT ON table2  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO record VALUES (id,NEW.sent); 
INSERT INTO temp values (id,NEW.sent,NEW.pcount,NEW.ncount); 

END

$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

new delimiter must be on another line

Comment: thanks but while executing above in mysql terminal, after entering $$ when I press query executed saying `trigger command denied to user '@' localhost for table table2 `

Comment: even when I put it in text file and executed entire script, it says `ERROR 1142 (42000): TRIGGER command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'table2'
`

Comment: maybe the database user lack some privileges

Comment: I tried in that direction also : `mysql> show grants for 'ec2-user';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
mysql> show grants for ec2-user;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-user' at line 1
`

Comment: try creating the trigger using the root user

Comment: means? I start mysql `sudo ./mysql` so what ever I create will be created as root user only na

Comment: just create the trigger with root, then figure out how to solve the permission issue with the other user